# Casting vector from one class to other class vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to push the values of 1 class vector to other class vector using dynamic casting.  But I am getting a segmentation fault.

When I debugged the program using gdb I found that `dynamic_cast` is not happening so there is no value to push to the vector.

Here I am trying to copy the elements from `std::vector<BPatch_point *> *points` to `std::vector<ldframework::Point *> *lpoints`.

`BPatch_point` and `Point` are completely unrelated classes.

Could you please help me on this?

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

        BPatch bpatch;
        int pid;
        if (argc != 3) {

                exit(1);
        }

        pid=atoi(argv[1]);

        char name[ 40 ];
        cout<<"The attached pid is "<<pid<<endl;


        BPatch_process *appProc = bpatch.processAttach("",pid);
        BPatch_image *img = appProc->getImage();

        std::vector<BPatch_function *> functions;
        std::vector<BPatch_point *> *points;


        img->findFunction(argv[2], functions);
        if(functions.size()==0) {
                cout<<"unable to find the function "<<argv[2]<<endl;
                return -1;
        }
        else {
              cout<<"The "<<argv[2]<<" function is found"<<endl;
        }
        points = functions[0]->findPoint(BPatch_entry);
        if ((*points).size() == 0) {
                cout<<"Not able to find the points"<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"The points is "<<(*points)[0];
        std::vector<ldframework::Point *> *lpoints=NULL;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<(*points).size();i++)
    {
        lpoints->push_back(dynamic_cast<ldframework::Point *>((*points).at(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to do each element on its own, or just use a std::vector<boost::any>>

Comment: What's the relationship between BPatch_point and Point?

Comment: I am new to c++ programming. I tried adding 1 element at a time. But still its giving segmentation fault.

Comment: BPatch_point and Point are completely unrelated classess.

Comment: Then what do you expect that cast to do? You'll need some sort of conversion if they're unrelated.

Comment: I am not sure of what conevrsion can be done when both are vectors but of different classes

Comment: You need a conversion between `BPatch_point` and `ldframework::Point`; the fact that they're stored in vectors is irrelevant.

Comment: According to the relation between two classes,you should implement casting operator on BPatch_point class for conversion.

Comment: You are asking us how to convert an object of class A to an object of unrelated class B without giving any information on A and B. What answer are you expecting?

Comment: Judging from the names I would guess that both `BPatch_point` and `ldframework::Point` consist of a 2-dimensional point with an `x` and a `y` coordinate. In that case you can implement the conversion quite easy.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is transform objects one by one, not cast them. Fortunately the standard library makes it very easy.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

ClassB * ConvertAtoB(ClassA * a)
{
    // create a new object of type ClassB here
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<ClassA*> a;

    // fill 'a' with data
    // ...

    // then transform it into 'b'
    std::vector<ClassB*> b;
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), ConvertAtoB);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Here I am trying to copy the elements from std::vector *points to std::vector *lpoints. Could you please help me on this?
>
> BPatch_point and Point are completely unrelated classess.

This can be translated to:

> I have a zoo with elephants. Can you please help me on how can I convert these elephants to oranges and put them in an orange container box?

When classes are unrelated, their only common thing is `void *` - "a pointer to something". Another option is to use a placeholder for any value - such as `boost::any`.

But the core question is: *why* do you want to move classes of one type to container of classes of another type. There's 99.8% chance, that you're doing something wrong in the first place and that's the place you should find solution for.

---

**Edit:** (in response to comments)

> Can you please suggest how it can be done using boost::any method or void * method

Replace `std::vector<ldframework::Point *>` with either `std::vector<boost::any>` (if you can use boost library in your project) or `std::vector<void *>`. Then you will be able to put anything there.

Though I'm still pretty convinced, that you're doing something very wrong. Feel free to use the described solution though if you **really** know, what you're doing.

Comment: For my project requirements it needs to be done. I am 100% sure this needs to be done. But I am not aware of how it can be done. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @user2659232 _'But I am not aware of it can be done.'_ No it cannot be done with unrelated classes and `dynamic_cast<>`.

Comment: ok. I am really sorry then. Can you please suggest how it can be done using boost::any method or void * method

Comment: @user2659232 Please provide a conclusive reason for this (in the question, not in the comments), i.e. explain the requirement that forces you to do this mad conversion. As Spook suggested, this is very very bad programming practice.

Comment: `std::vector<void *>` screams for a follow up question "How do I convert a `void *` back to its original type?".

Comment: @nwp I know - that will possibly cause a lot more problems. But without more specific context I guess this is as good answer as I can give...

Comment: This answer is correct *but* it leads in a wrong direction I think. The same would apply for any `reinterpret_cast` answer. Yes, you can do all this but in the vast majority of cases it is not what you need.